# Jquery Autocomplete issue without php

Tags: jquery

hi everyone i am trying to do an autocomplete on a textarea in a form
and I am trying to do it without PHP and sql only Jquery i have tried this :

```
    var auto = $(function() {
      $( "#recherche").autocomplete({
      source: [
     "Draggable",
     "Droppable",
     "Resizable",
     "Selectable",
     "Sortable"
      ],
      minLength: 2,
      })});
```

recherche is my id for my input were i have a label so does anyone see what is the issue ?
Thanks.

when i took your exemple in a single page it work but in my page it doesn't tell me error but it's not working do you know why ??

Comment: What framework/plugin are you using? There is no `autocomplete` method in vanilla jQuery.

Comment: did you include jqueryUI link in script?

Comment: yes i included a library here is what i did :

     <script src="libs/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
and here is the error message : uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function about this line : 
           $( "#recherche").autocomplete({
i thought i did it right and the html line is :

     <input type="text" class="searchable" value="{{producteur}}" name="producteur"/>

Comment: @user3841419 no you have to include both jQuery and jQuery UI, jQuery UI is another library not part of jQuery core

Comment: i didn't know that where can i find it ?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine after including jQueryUI lib. Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGn6t/).

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="recherche">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#recherche").autocomplete({
    source: [
      "Draggable",
      "Droppable",
      "Resizable",
      "Selectable",
      "Sortable"
    ],
    minLength: 2,
  })
});
```

Comment: yes i included a library here is what i did :

     <script src="libs/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
and here is the error message : uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function about this line : 
           $( "#recherche").autocomplete({
i thought i did it right and the html line is :

     <input type="text" class="searchable" value="{{producteur}}" name="producteur"/>

Comment: wow thanks man can you give me the links to downloads   jQueryUI lib.